# Why define Spin$(2)$ as the double cover, not universal cover, of SO$(2)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory, lie-groups, clifford-algebras, spin-geometry

For $n>2,$ the [spin group](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spin_group) Spin$(n)$ is isomorphic to the [universal cover](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Covering_space#Universal_covering) of SO$(n)$. In these cases, the universal covers can be explicitly constructed using the Clifford algebra over $\mathbb R^n$. Spin$(2)$ is defined using the Clifford algebra construction, which yields a double-cover of SO$(2)$ [as it does for all SO$(n)$], but this is **not** the universal cover of SO$(2)$, namely $\mathbb R$. **Is there a good reason to define Spin(2) as this double cover, rather than the universal cover?** Or if that seems too subjective, then: **Is there any special significance to this double-cover of SO(2), say, in representation theory, Lie theory, or topology?**

I ask because the universal cover seems more significant to me, although I am somewhat of a novice in this area. But in physics, we care especially about *projective representations* of Lie groups, which are related (by several results, e.g., [Bargmann's theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Projective_representation#Projective_representations_of_Lie_groups)) to the *universal cover*, not necessarily the double cover.

**Edit.** A related question and generalization (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801152/topological-definition-of-spinp-q)) is to include orthogonal groups of indefinite signature in this discussion.

Comment: For $n>2$, the universal cover is the double cover, so taking the double cover means there is a consistent algebraic construction for all $n$.  Also, this means we will always be compact, which the universal cover of $SO(2)$ is not.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant. There is a canonical linear isomorphism between exterior algebra and any Clifford algebra (in characteristic not 2), so we can use that language when talking about Clifford algebras. Speaking just about Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, every element of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)\subset\mathrm{Cl}_n(\mathbb R)$ is of the form $e^B$ where $B$ is a *bivector*, and conversely every bivector gives an element of $\mathrm{Spin}(n)$. The bivectors represent the Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SO}(n)$ using the Clifford product commutator $[B,B']=BB'-B'B$. This is true for all $n$.

Comment: The most important thing about the spin groups is the 2-to-1 map down to $SO(n)$, so the double adjective is more important than the universal one (though as you point out, for $n>2$ there isn't any difference at all).

Comment: @Randall Important how/why? Naïvely, I would think the universal cover is more important, because we care about projective reps of SO$(n)$, and there are theorems showing that these descend from honest reps of the universal cover (I think).

Comment: $\text{Spin}(2)$ is an $S^1$...

Answer (score -6):

This is what you need to make sense of Dirac operators; this is what you need to see the relation to theta characteristics. These classical topics are more important than the sense that Spin should be a universal cover. (Take it as a mantra: the *point* is Dirac operators.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The information as written here is helpful and sufficient; I'm not going to add a "let me Google that for you" link, nor am I going to write a short textbook.