# Topological definition of Spin$(p,q)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, covering-spaces, spin-geometry

In short, **How can we define Spin(p, q) without referencing Clifford algebras?** The answer should be something like "Spin$(p, q)$ is the unique double cover of SO$^+(p, q)$ such that ...". Wikipedia seems to think we can omit the "such that ...", [claiming](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Spin_representation#Set-up):

> Up to group isomorphism, SO$(V, Q)$ has a unique connected double cover, the spin group Spin$(V, Q)$.

[Here $Q$ is a nondegenerate quadratic form over a real or complex vector space $V$, so we can equivalently replace SO$(V, Q)$ with SO$^+(p,q)$. Wikipedia also omits the $^+$ but says that they are referring to the identity component.]

But the above claim is [false](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4609709/does-sov-q-have-a-unique-connected-double-cover/4609719#4609719). One alternative approach is to define the spin groups by explicitly constructing them with Clifford algebras, but I'd like to know of a purely topological definition, as described above.

---

I originally asked this question as a footnote to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592418/why-define-spin2-as-the-double-cover-not-universal-cover-of-so2), then decided to move it here. Along with the definition requested above, I'd also appreciate some discussion of why the definition is "morally correct" or useful.

Comment: I think the "moral" definition is that it is the "smallest" group which has both spin representations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost nobody does this. There is a discussion in the Wikipedia article on spinor groups but it has too many mistakes and too few references. The only solid math reference I know is in Chapter 5 (freely available from author's webpage [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Evsv/papers/ch5.pdf)) in

*Varadarajan, V. S.*, Supersymmetry for mathematicians: an introduction., Courant Lecture Notes in Mathematics 11. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS); New York, NY: Courant Institute of Mathematical Sciences (ISBN 0-8218-3574-2/pbk). vi, 300 p. (2004). [ZBL1142.58009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1142.58009).

It is useful if you read this answer in conjunction with my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865317/double-cover-vs-universal-cover-for-rm-sop-q/4865614#4865614).

To describe $Spin(p,q)$ as a 2-fold cover of $SO^+(p,q)$ ($p>1, q>1$) one has to look at the maximal compact subgroups since they carry all the homotopy information. The group $SO^+(p,q)$ has maximal compact subgroup $SO(p)\times SO(q)$ and
$$
\pi_1(SO^+(p,q))\cong \pi_1(SO(p)\times SO(q))\cong H_1\times H_2,
$$
where $H_1, H_2$ are cyclic groups (either infinite cyclic or ${\mathbb Z}_2$). In particular, if $h_1, h_2$ are generators of $H_1, H_2$, then there is a homomorphism
$$
\phi: H_1\times H_2\to {\mathbb Z}_2,
$$
sending both $h_1, h_2$ to the generator of ${\mathbb Z}_2$. It is clear that these homomorphisms are independent of the choices of generators. Let $H< H_1\times H_2$ denote the kernel of $\phi$, it is an index 2 subgroup in $\pi_1(SO(p)\times SO(q)\cong \pi_1(SO^+(p,q))$. Then $Spin(p,q)$ is the 2-fold cover of $SO^+(p,q)$ associated with the subgroup $H$ of the fundamental group. This is your topological description of the spinor group.

In  Varadarajan's terminology, here is what's going on. The (unique up to conjugation) maximal compact subgroup of $Spin(p,q)$ is $(Spin(p)\times Spin(q))/G$, where $G\cong {\mathbb Z}_2$ is generated by an element $(a,b)\in Spin(p)\times Spin(q)$, where $a, b$ are the nontrivial central elements of $Spin(p), Spin(q)$ respectively, such that
$$
Spin(p)/\langle a\rangle = SO(p), Spin(q)/\langle b\rangle = SO(q).
$$
Hence, $(a,b)$ corresponds to the "diagonal" element $(h_1, h_2)$ of $H_1\times H_2$.